# Where should I properly make an AJAX call in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, ajax

I'm confused, in the official React Js documentation, it indicates that [I should make all the AJAX calls in componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html), what if I want to make the call inside an onClick or onChange event handler. I should be forced to make the AJAX calls in componentDidMount?

AJAX in an method or eventhandler

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
    handleChange(e) {
        //ajax
        getUser(e.target.value).then(data => console.log(data))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value='1'>jim</option>
                    <option value='2'>sarah</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Or inside `componentDidMount`, as the documentation says

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { valueSelected: null }
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            valueSelected: e.target.value
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //ajax
        if (this.state.valueSelected)
            getUser(this.state.valueSelected).then(data => console.log(data))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value='1'>jim</option>
                    <option value='2'>sarah</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `What if I want to make the call inside an onClick or onChange event handler` That's fine; do it in onClick or onChange.

Comment: There is no problem not doing it according to the documentation?

Comment: The article is talking about which *lifecycle hooks* to do ajax calls in. And if you're using a lifecycle hook, then componentDidMount is the most likely candidate. But your case is unrelated to lifecycle hooks. There is no problem with using onClick or onChange if you want it to happen on click or on change.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { 
    valueSelected: null,
    isUpdate : false,
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
 handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({
    valueSelected: e.target.value,
    isUpdate : !this.state.isUpdate,
   })
}
componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({
   valueSelected: '1',
   isUpdate : !this.state.isUpdate,
 })
 //ajax
  if (this.state.valueSelected)
    // getUser(this.state.valueSelected).then(data => console.log(data))
    
 fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.state.valueSelected}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
 }
 componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps){
 if(prevState.isUpdate !== this.state.isUpdate){
  // getUser(this.state.valueSelected).then(data => console.log(data))
  
 fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.state.valueSelected}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
  }
}
render() {
  return (
     <div>
        <form>
            <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value='1'>jim</option>
                <option value='2'>sarah</option>
            </select>
        </form>
     </div>
  )
 }
}
```